# How do I remove the "Shipping & Handling" section from the totals section on the cart page?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping

I'm talking about this section: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUqxB.jpg

I've found `totals.phtml` at `template/checkout/cart/totals.phtml` but it renders all totals uniformly.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to remove the shipping AND handling from the files, then you an do it this way, make sure you copy this to your local as you should not edit the core files.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Shipping.php
```

The Shipping & Handling text can be edited in there or removed:

```
'title'=>Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping & Handling').' ('.$address->getShippingDescription().')',
```

The shipping method and title etc can edited on line 155

```
$address->setShippingDescription($rate->getCarrierTitle().’ - ’.$rate->getMethodTitle());
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends how you want to change it.

Copy the core file:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Shipping.php
```

to the local side. Here are some examples of how to do it.

If you just want to remove the "Shipping & Handling (" section, delete around line 188:

```
$title = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping & Handling');
```

and change around line 190

```
$title .= ' (' . $address->getShippingDescription() . ')';
```

to

```
$title = $address->getShippingDescription();
```

Or to go from "Shipping & Handling (Flat Rate Shipping - Priority First Class)" to "Flat Rate Shipping", still delete line 188 (as above) but also change around line 190 from

```
$title .= ' (' . $address->getShippingDescription() . ')';
```

to

```
$title = strstr( $address->getShippingDescription(), ' -', true);
```

Hope this helps